# The center of gravity of string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

A uniform string of mass $M$ and length $2a$ is placed symmetrically over a smooth peg and has particles of masses $m$ and $m'$ attached to its extremities Show that by the principle of energy that when the string runes off the peg .its velocity will be $$\displaystyle \sqrt{\frac{M+2(m-m')}{M+m+m'}ga} $$

**DOUBT**-In the solution in my book while driving this solution they are using the term '**Center of gravity** ' for calculating the work done by **gravity** on the string which is given that

**work one by gravity on string is**=$M\times g \times \displaystyle \frac{a}{2}$
i Don't know from where this $\frac{a}{2}$  come from

Please Help

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the string is uniform (i.e. it has the same mass per unit length all along its length) it can be treated as if it were a single particle of mass $M$ at its mid-point. Initially the string is hanging symmetrically on the peg so its mid-point is at the height of the peg. When the string runs off the peg its mid-point has fallen by a distance $\frac a 2$, so the work done on the string by gravity is $Mg\frac a 2$.